# Create 4-dimensional NxNxMxM array using 2-dimension NxM array as diagonal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking to perform the following operation: A[i,j,a,b] = δ <sub>ij</sub> δ <sub>ab</sub> B[i,a]. Where A is a NxNxMxM array and B is a NxM array and the δ symbols corresponds to the Kronecker delta.
This can be easily done using explicit looping.

```
A = np.zeros((N,N,M,M))
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(N):
      for a in range(M):
         for b in range(M):
            if i == j and a == b:
               A[i,j,a,b] = B[i,a]
```

However, there must be easier and faster ways to perform such operations.

Answer (score 0):

A much shorter way (but still maybe not the most optimal) is to do the following:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCoMwDMfveYocGyji5k6DHfSuLyAyBLuth6al1YN7@a6lGy6EfP1/CXH7@rLcxKiNs35F3ozbcQ7IDthVfubFmiootYgLwSCxxxueJTbQpeIgctK8ilriqU5BZJQInM/TjqAt@Ft5G0RWM1CYOS0/1d0UonSiJ3hYjxo1Y5kMdAVM1o5CS0z@2zsqmtKNbvzTpu8HLUGMHw)

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(4)
N, M = 2, 3
B = np.random.randint(0, 100, (N, M))
print(B)
A = np.zeros((N, N, M, M))
arange_m = np.arange(M)
for i in range(N):
    A[(i, i, arange_m, arange_m)] = B[i, arange_m]
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[[46 55 69]
 [ 1 87 72]]


[[[[46.  0.  0.]
   [ 0. 55.  0.]
   [ 0.  0. 69.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]]


 [[[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 1.  0.  0.]
   [ 0. 87.  0.]
   [ 0.  0. 72.]]]]
```

---

I just found even shorter way doing same thing using mesh-grid:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xC4MwEIX3/IobEwiitVOhg@46dRMpgkEdkhwXHeyfTy9oscu9x3sfj8N9nb0rY1wselrBbRZ3GAI4FA4zGtzobRaMGeVdiVZDA0@4aShFzeYikixulbmGIucjE6qUQEpprUR14B9DPsjUJuBg7HR01oR5omWUafbdPdpew2kbtgEHCobRF22GBztppy7n4pLiJ6pnrv4nUnZ@U6kYvw)

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(4)
N, M = 2, 3
B = np.random.randint(0, 100, (N, M))
print(B)
A = np.zeros((N, N, M, M))
mg = np.meshgrid(np.r_[:N], np.r_[:M], sparse = True)
A[(mg[0], mg[0], mg[1], mg[1])] = B[(mg[0], mg[1])]
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[[46 55 69]
 [ 1 87 72]]


[[[[46.  0.  0.]
   [ 0. 55.  0.]
   [ 0.  0. 69.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]]


 [[[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]

  [[ 1.  0.  0.]
   [ 0. 87.  0.]
   [ 0.  0. 72.]]]]
```